# Apache Cordova Android 5.0 Select Box Option color

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I am attempting to update an Apache Cordova Application to target Android 5.0. Everything seems to be functional so far as I can tell but I am encountering a cosmetic issue when opening a select box. The list options appear on my Nexus 7 running 5.0 with a white background and light gray text color such that the options are nearly unreadable. I have already attempted the following and more:

- Setting the color and background-color of the options through CSS.
- Setting -webkit-appearance:none through CSS on both the SELECT and OPTION elements.
- Changing the theme from Theme.Black.NoTitleBar to pretty much every option available without a titlebar. The only thing this accomplished was a few that set the color of the options to white with a background color of white as well.

Sample HTML code and yes I know I'm not including cordova.js at this time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This is my title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <select name="hellow">
                <option>A</option>
                <option>B</option>
                <option>C</option>
                <option>D</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" value="Text!"/>
            <select name="world">
                <option>A</option>
                <option>B</option>
                <option>C</option>
                <option>D</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: After quite some time I was able to figure this out. I was apparently jsut changing the theme for the Application tag in the manifest.xml and needed to make the change in both the application and activity tags. After changing both to "android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" I now have black text on white backgrounds in my app.

Comment: Your resolution in the above comment worked for me too. You should answer your own question with this answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have done so now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After quite some time I was able to figure this out. I was apparently jsut changing the theme for the Application tag in the manifest.xml and needed to make the change in both the application and activity tags. After changing both to "android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" I now have black text on white backgrounds in my app.

Comment: But this way the style will go away everytime i build the application right? How would you do that?