# Change select style in cordova app

Tags: html, cordova

Is it possible to change the style of options of select tag?

I think Since the options list populated in the ios/android phone is OS specific, CSS or javascript cannot change the appearance of the same.
Is there any way do that(i.e. change the style of the select option)?

Comment: Hi @Mantu. My answer has helped to solve your issue? If so, can you [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark? This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Did you find the solution @Mantu Nigam? I am stuck at the same issue.

Comment: @RohitSingh to overcome that issue we had used ion-select instead of native one.

Answer (score 0):

Without working directly on native code, no. As you said, CSS and JavaScript can't change the appearance of the natively rendered options. As a alternative, you can use, for example, a jQuery plugin instead of the default input and customize the style of it.

Here [some alternatives](https://www.sitepoint.com/13-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/).

Another alternative is write a Cordova plugin to achieve your goal.

Some related questions:

- [PhoneGap & Android - How to use the new select list style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090494/phonegap-android-how-to-use-the-new-select-list-style)
- [Styling the first option of a  input on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651507/styling-the-first-option-of-a-select-input-on-ios)
- [Apache Cordova Android 5.0 Select Box Option color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27025345/apache-cordova-android-5-0-select-box-option-color)

Comment: How can we change the appearance in XCODE?